# Windows Account Locking policy different while editing scheduled task

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, accounts, locking

When I connect (through RDP) on my Windows 2008 R2 server and editing a task from the "Task Scheduler" if I enter a wrong password, the account is immediately locked.

This happens with Domain user and with local admin users.

However when I am looking to the Group Policies Editor (gpedit.msc) I can see the value:

```
Account lockout threshold: 5 invalid login attempts
```

Is there another setting which manage specifically the "Task Scheduler" account locking policy or the problem comes from another part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue where the credentials were sent multiple times and locked out the account. This [hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2548120/account-is-incorrectly-locked-after-you-create-or-change-multiple-sche) addresses that.

Comment: Thanks, it looks a good reason, however it seems we install all Windows Updates regularly. It seems we're in SP1 already and some  updates more. The link is not very clear on how to check if that fix has already been applied or not. Any thoughts?